# Is calling elements(?) on a selected set possible?

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I have two entities which they have a many-to-many relationship. E.g. AEnt and BEnt:

```
class AEnt {
    //....
    String name;
    Set<BEnt> bs;
 }

class BEnt {
    //....
 }
```

I want to select such BEnts where the names of their AEnts are like "somthing". My query now is like this:

```
from BEnt b where b in 
     (select elements(a.bs) from AEnt a where a.name like :name)
```

But the problem is Hibernate at first calls elements on all AEnts-BEnts and in fact ignores my "like" filter. Because I have millions of AEnt-BEnt relations, the query becomes not responding. Is there a way to call elements just on the selected set of AEnts? Or a better query?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a reference to `AEnt` in `BEnt` - ie a many-to-one, given you have a one-to-mant relationship between `AEnt` and `BEnt`. Try this:

```
from BEnt b where b.a.name like :name
```